# Python - Flask image upload failing without error

Tags: python, flask, multipartform-data

Im posting the following data to my flask image upload server.  Problem is an image does not get saved. There are no errors in console.

I have tried decoding the image bytes and it seems to be a properly formed multipart request.

So why isn't the image uploading properly?

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
import sys

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/Users/admin/Desktop/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.get_data(), file=sys.stdout)
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=file.filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Quick test configuration. Please use proper Flask configuration options
    # in production settings, and use a separate file or environment variables
    # to manage the secret key!
    app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'

    # sess.init_app(app)

    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Data im posting: (I captured it using `print(request.get_data(), file=sys.stdout)` located in code)

https://pastecode.io/s/cpev4ny4

Answer (score 0):

could you please verify if your apache or whatever you use has permission to write ( save an image) in that directory?

Comment: Yes, it works fine when I use the image upload on homepage.